# Conda Installation python -v returns traceback

Tags: python, anaconda

I just installed Anaconda onto my computer, but when I run `python -v`, a bunch of import stastements that look like a stacktrace gets spit out onto my terminal. Any idea what might've gone wrong and how I can fix it?

```
~ % python -v
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'posix' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _thread # previously loaded ('_thread')
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _weakref # previously loaded ('_weakref')
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'time' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/__init__.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc'
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/codecs.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/codecs.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/codecs.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'codecs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbed6d8490>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/aliases.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'encodings.aliases' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef168a60>
import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbed6d8280>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/utf_8.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'encodings.utf_8' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbed6d82e0>
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/__pycache__/latin_1.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/latin_1.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/encodings/__pycache__/latin_1.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'encodings.latin_1' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef168b50>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/io.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/io.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/io.cpython-38.pyc'
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/abc.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/abc.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/abc.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef168fd0>
import 'io' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef168d00>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/site.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/site.cpython-38.pyc'
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/os.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/os.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/os.cpython-38.pyc'
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/stat.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/stat.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/stat.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'stat' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef1fd940>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/_collections_abc.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/_collections_abc.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/_collections_abc.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_collections_abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef1fd9d0>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/posixpath.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/posixpath.cpython-38.pyc'
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/genericpath.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/genericpath.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'genericpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef220310>
import 'posixpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef1fda60>
import 'os' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef183fa0>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/_sitebuiltins.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/_sitebuiltins.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/_sitebuiltins.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_sitebuiltins' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef194940>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/_bootlocale.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/_bootlocale.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/_bootlocale.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_locale' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_bootlocale' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef220730>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/types.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/types.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/types.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'types' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef220a00>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc'
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/warnings.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/warnings.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/warnings.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'warnings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef2735b0>
import 'importlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef273220>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__pycache__/util.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/util.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__pycache__/util.cpython-38.pyc'
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__pycache__/abc.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/abc.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__pycache__/abc.cpython-38.pyc'
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__pycache__/machinery.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/machinery.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__pycache__/machinery.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'importlib.machinery' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef285df0>
import 'importlib.abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef285190>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/contextlib.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/contextlib.cpython-38.pyc'
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/collections/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/collections/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc'
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/operator.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/operator.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/operator.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_operator' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'operator' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef2ba340>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/keyword.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/keyword.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/keyword.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'keyword' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef2ba430>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/heapq.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/heapq.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/heapq.cpython-38.pyc'
# extension module '_heapq' loaded from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module '_heapq' executed from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import '_heapq' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef2bad60>
import 'heapq' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef2ba5b0>
import 'itertools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/reprlib.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/reprlib.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/reprlib.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'reprlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef2ba940>
import '_collections' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'collections' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef29d520>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/functools.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/functools.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/functools.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_functools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'functools' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef29d6d0>
import 'contextlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef2857f0>
import 'importlib.util' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef273400>
# possible namespace for /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits
# destroy sphinxcontrib
# destroy sphinxcontrib
# destroy sphinxcontrib
# destroy sphinxcontrib
# destroy sphinxcontrib
# destroy sphinxcontrib
# destroy zope
# zipimport: found 7 names in '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locket-0.2.1-py3.8.egg'
import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef183970>
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 12:59:45)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
# extension module 'readline' loaded from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-38-darwin.so'
# extension module 'readline' executed from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-38-darwin.so'
import 'readline' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef2c7ee0>
import 'atexit' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/rlcompleter.cpython-38.pyc matches /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/rlcompleter.py
# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/rlcompleter.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'rlcompleter' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fbbef29d880>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you run `python --help` you will see that:

```
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
         can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity
```

you are probably looking for:

```
-V     : print the Python version number and exit (also --version)
```

notice the uppercase `V` and lowercase `v`

Comment: I assumed you wanted to print the python version, although you didn't mention it in the original question

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are trying to check the installation was successful and check python version. You can either run one of these commands

```
python --version
```

or

```
python -V
```

you can check the documentation here: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#